# using not in querySelector with spaces

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I'd like to retrieve all elements which are not child's of other element.
i had tried this code example (that seems like a perfectly valid css3 selector to me):

```
document.querySelector("span:not(p span)")
```

its doesn't work in chrome , what shall i do?

Comment: @charlietfl: That single line of code is all the MCVE you need. Run it and it'll throw a SYNTAX_ERR.

Comment: @BoltClock was thinking along the lines of sample html. May or may not be important but certainly helpful and less prone to gess work

Comment: @charlietfl: Fair enough. That can be gleaned from the selector as well - a span that is not a descendant of p, but it might not always be what the asker intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could add a class to all `p span` and then use that class as a `not` filter

```
var pSpans = document.querySelector("p span");
for(var i=0; i<pSpans.length; i++){
  pSpans[i].classList.add('p-span');
}

var notPspans = document.querySelector("span:not(.p-span)")
```

Answer (score 2):

[Support for the selector list argument of :not](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list) is currently limited to Safari and Mobile Safari. Other browsers do not yet support it and treat the selector as invalid instead.

Basic `:not()` support only allows *simple selectors*, which do not support descendant combinators.

Alternative approaches you may be able to take include:

- Setting the rules for *all* `span`s and then writing different rules for `p span` elements.
- Writing a selector that matches the elements in some other way, such as `body > span`.

The specifics would depend on the precise nature of your markup.